# JSON viewer in grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

So here is my code it run fines and it return back the json. But the problem is I installed JSON viewer in chrome and it would not format into that view it still show JSON as a text.Is it because of the code?I already specified the content type.

```
def getTicket() {
    def httpRequest = new HTTPBuilder('example.com')
    httpRequest.auth.basic('email', 'password')
    httpRequest.contentType = JSON
    httpRequest.request(Method.GET)
            {
                response.success = { resp, json ->
                    render json
                }
                response.failure = { resp, json ->
                    render "Request failed with status ${resp.status}" + json

                }

            }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://guides.grails.org/using-hal-with-json-views/guide/index.html this will help you

Comment: "I already specified the content type" - Where is that specified?

Comment: Sorry I thought I did but I haven't and I fixed the issues by specified the content type. Thank you